# Do this if a checkbox is ticked, do this on uncheck

Tags: jquery

I am having a bit of trouble with ticking/unticking checkboxes.

I am currently using jquery vs 1.4

The Problem:

I have a list of checkboxes who's id's are generated by a PHP loop.

i.e

- tickbox 1 id = checkthis_1
- tickbox 2 id = checkthis_2
- tickbox 3 id = checkthis_3
- and so on

When I check a tickbox I want to get the id of that checkbox (1, 2 or 3) and add that to a hidden field. When that same tickbox is unticked I want to remove its id from the hidden field.

i.e

I tick checkbox 3, the number 3 goes into my hidden field. When I untick checkbox 3, the number 3 is removed from the hidden field.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you show your code?

Comment: Given that you know a checkbox is, in fact, a checkbox; what do you mean by 'tickbox'? Is that meant to be a class-name, or name of the group, or some other identifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime a checkbox is clicked, go thru all checked checkboxes and concatenate their ids..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {

        var result = '';

        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            result += $(this).attr('id') + ';'
        });

        $('#your-hidden-field-id').val(result);

    });

});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pYFga/)

Or another way of doing that using [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method:

```
$('#your-hidden-field-id').val($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get().join(';'));
```

Answer (score 1):

With a checkbox with the id of same...

```
 $("input#same").click(function () {
                  if ($("input#same").is(':checked')) {
                      // Checked, copy values
                      Your Hide Code

                  }
                  else {
                      // On uncheck
                      Other stuff

                  }
              });
```

So basically there